# Drupal 7 add new module link missing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm not able to find "install new module" link on my multisite production environment. But, the link of "install new module" is appearing in my local. I have checked, the user permission in production site, and enabled Update Manager module, also, comment $conf['allow_authorize_operations'] = FALSE; in setting.php. But still it's not appearing.

Thanks, for looking the response.

[Click here to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SABAS.png)

Comment: Have you cleared your menu cache and checked again. If you still dont find it then login via superadmin and goto {your-domain}/admin/modules/install

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I cleared the cache many times. Also, I have checked there is no "superadmin" under people->permission->roles

Comment: may be there is a role of admin in people->permission->roles who has all the permissions in you site

Comment: In edit permission all the checkbox are checked. Would you please tell me where I can find Super Admin role.

Comment: Super admin role has role id of 3, but it can be of any name. You can find all the permissions at admin/people/permissions and all roles at admin/people/permissions/roles

Comment: In your image Administrator is the super admin role.

Comment: Viswanath, in my local environment, the add new module link is appearing. But, it is not appearing in my production site.

Comment: can you view the url on server {your-domain}/admin/modules/install

Comment: have you configured Temporary directory directory in {your-domain}admin/config/media/file-system